# Avoid edgelines or overlaps for coloring a plot using cmap and plt.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to color a plot from red to green continuously (changing smoothly) based on 4 different styles along `y` axis, using `cmap`, where the first and the last sections are colored by constant colors red and green respectively. I want to use `plt.imshow` in this regard, if it could. I wrote the following code for that, inspiring from other posts and based on my needs, but it get some overlaps or edge colors between sections. The sections must be colored such how the first section is red (the 1st color of `cmap`), the 2nd section must change from that red smoothly to yellow, the 3rd one must continue from the last red to green, and the last be that green constantly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (19.2, 9.6)

Diam_P = 0.4
ylim = 7

plt.imshow(np.interp(np.linspace(0, 3 * Diam_P, 1), [0, 1], [0, 0]).reshape(-1, 1),
           cmap='hsv', vmin=0, vmax=1, extent=[0, 180, 0, 3 * Diam_P], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)
plt.imshow(np.interp(np.linspace(3 * Diam_P, 2, 10000), [3 * Diam_P, 2], [0, 0.15]).reshape(-1, 1),
           cmap='hsv', vmin=0, vmax=1, extent=[0, 180, 3 * Diam_P, 2], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)
plt.imshow(np.interp(np.linspace(2, 3, 20000), [2, 3], [0.15, 0.24]).reshape(-1, 1),
           cmap='hsv', vmin=0, vmax=1, extent=[0, 180, 2, 3], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)
plt.imshow(np.interp(np.linspace(3, ylim, 1), [3, ylim], [0.24, 0.24]).reshape(-1, 1),
           cmap='hsv', vmin=0, vmax=1, extent=[0, 180, 3, ylim], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)

plt.xlim(0, 70)
plt.ylim(0, ylim)
plt.savefig("test2.png", dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem is edgelines or overlaps which are appeared on the plot and as can be seen, colors not changed continuously from yellow to green (darker green at first and then lighter green, which is not as expected):

[image]

I would be grateful for solutions solving these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the bands overlap, the alpha blending creates a darker line.  You can avoid this either by not using alpha, or by drawing the image in one go.

## Using 'hsv' with a stretched image

To draw everything in one go:

- start with a linear "image" with enough subdivisions going from `0` to `ylim`
- use `np.interp` to map the values:

  - `0` to "color" `0` (red in 'hsv')
  - `3 * Diam_P` also to "color" `0`
  - `2` to "color" `0.15` (yellow)
  - `3` to "color" `0.24` (green)
  - `ylim` also to "color" `0.15`
- draw the mapped image via `imshow` with `vmin=0`, `vmax=1` and `cmap='hsv'`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Diam_P = 0.4
ylim = 7
linear_img = np.linspace(0, ylim, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
stretched_img = np.interp(linear_img,
                          [0, 3 * Diam_P, 2, 3, ylim],
                          [0, 0, 0.15, 0.24, 0.24])
plt.imshow(stretched_img, cmap='hsv',
           vmin=0, vmax=1, extent=[0, 180, 0, ylim], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', zorder=-1, alpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

[image: imshow with banded image and alpha]

## Using a stretched colormap with a linear image

Alternatively, you can work with a `LinearSegmentedColormap` that maps the boundaries to the 3 given colors.  For this mapping, the boundaries first need to be transformed to the range `0`-`1`.  This will create a linear mapping from the given red to the given yellow to the given green, without going through the colors present in the 'hsv' colormap. (The mapping is linear is RGB space, not in hue.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

Diam_P = 0.4
ylim = 7

linear_img = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
red, yellow, green = plt.get_cmap('hsv')([0, 0.15, 0.24])
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('',
                                         [(0, red),
                                          (3 * Diam_P / ylim, red),
                                          (2 / ylim, yellow),
                                          (3 / ylim, green),
                                          (1, green)])
plt.imshow(linear_img, cmap=cmap,
           extent=[0, 180, 0, ylim], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', alpha=0.7, zorder=-1)
plt.show()
```

[image: using a LinearSegmentedColormap]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the first solution better distribute the colors than the second one as could be seen for the 3rd section (the second solution is not good in this section), but the second one is more smoother in which gradual changes in colors are more hidden. [I compared it in an image with 10000 in `linspace` and gradual change in the first section (not just constant red for that)](https://ibb.co/yYXf6NG). Is there any way to make this gradual changes more hidden using the first solution?

Comment: The first solution is interpolating in hsv space, the second one in rgb. I think it is hard to come by a "better" solution without diving deep into rather subjective [color theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory). One approach could be to fetch more intermediate colors from the first solution and put them into the second.